# Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (JwtService, ?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [1] is available

Tags: authentication, dependency-injection, nestjs

I got this error: Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (JwtService, ?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [1] is available in the AuthModule context.

I am trying to use a Guard in Nestjs and I can't import the AuthService.

#### My app.module

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [typeormConfig],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) =>
        configService.get('typeorm'),
    }),
    AuthModule,
    UserModule,
    FormModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

#### My auth.module

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: process.env.SECRET_JWT,
    }),
    UserModule,
  ],
  providers: [AuthService],
  controllers: [AuthController],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

#### My auth.service

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService extends AbstractService {
  constructor(
    private readonly JWTService: JwtService,
    private readonly userService: UserService,
  ) {
    super(AuthService.name);
  }

    ...
}
```

#### My user.module

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity])],
  providers: [UserService],
  exports: [UserService],
  controllers: [UserController],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

#### My user.service

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService extends AbstractService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
    private usersRepository: Repository<UserEntity>,
  ) {
    super(UserService.name);
  }

  ...
}
```

#### My auth.guard

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard extends AbstractGuard {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    super(AuthGuard.name);
  }

   ...
}
```

#### My form.module (the module that I use the guard)

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([FormEntity, UserEntity]), QuestionModule],
  exports: [FormService],
  providers: [FormService],
  controllers: [FormController],
})
export class FormModule {}
```

The ORM used for me in this project is the TypeORM.I'm using this abstracts classes to put some necessary code like the loggers and some logical. This is the full error:

```
[Nest] 12812  - 15/01/2024, 14:48:23   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (JwtService, ?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [1] is available in the AuthModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is AuthModule a valid NestJS module?
- If dependency is a provider, is it part of the current AuthModule?
- If dependency is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AuthModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing dependency */ ]
  })
```

#### My abstract.service

```
@Injectable()
export class AbstractService {
  protected readonly logger: Logger;

  constructor(context: string) {
    this.logger = new Logger(context);
  }
}
```

I tried to change the way that I'm importing the files and use the forward ref.

Comment: Can you add the `UserService` provider's constructor as well?

Comment: for sure, I made it

Comment: And `AbstractService`. From the looks of the error, there;'s a circular dependency somewhere, but with only seeing bits of your code, I can't track it down just yet

Comment: I did. I forgot to mention the module that I used the Guard, now I put it too.